# Calling a function in another file in python

Tags: python, function, call

I know this is a very common question, but the difference in here:
I want to call a function (f1) that is in test.py file from new.py file, I know how to do it but my main question is that: in test.py file I have some program lines that are not inside functions, so when I call the f1 function in new.py and run the new.py file, the test.py file also is running, how can I fix this and prevent from running other lines in test.py?
(in other words: how can I call a function in another file without running other lines that are in another file)
thanks

Comment: It will be easier to understand if you can provide some snippets of your codes.

Comment: put those top-level lines behind an `if __name__ == "__main__":` check to prevent them running when the code is only imported https://stackoverflow.com/q/419163/202168

Answer (score 1):

It's simple: don't have any statements at the top level, outside of functions, class declarations and so on.

But of course, you still want to be able to execute those lines if you invoke `test.py` directly (not as an import). There is a common idiom in Python for this:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    # Top-level statements go here, and are only executed
    # if this file is invoked as a script
```

See [What does `if __name__ == "__main__":` do](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/419163/what-does-if-name-main-do) for more information.